# Color Parse issue in android

Tags: android, progress-bar

I am parsing sky blue color with `hax` color as `Color.parseColor("#5bc0de")`. But don't know why it is showing green type color. I am using it with `ProgressBar` as
`pbScore.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(
 Color.parseColor("#5bc0de"), Mode.MULTIPLY);`

Am I doing anything wrong ?
I am testing this on real mobile device. I am using HTC One M9+.
**XML Code :**

```
<ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/pbScore"
                style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:max="60"
                android:progress="0" />
```

**Java Code :**

```
QuestionTimer cdtScore;
int iScore = 0;

pbScore = (ProgressBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pbScore);

public class QuestionTimer extends CountDownTimer {
        public QuestionTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
            super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        }

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            iScore++;
            pbScore.setProgress(iScore);

            if (iScore > 0 && iScore <= 15) {
                pbScore.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(
                        Color.parseColor("#f0ad4e"), Mode.MULTIPLY);
            } else if (iScore > 15 && iScore <= 30) {
                pbScore.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(
                        Color.parseColor("#5cb85c"), Mode.MULTIPLY);
            } else if (iScore > 30 && iScore <= 45) {
                pbScore.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(
                        Color.parseColor("#5bc0de"), Mode.MULTIPLY);
            } else if (iScore > 45) {
                pbScore.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(
                        Color.parseColor("#d9534f"), Mode.MULTIPLY);
            }

            pbScore.setProgress(iScore);
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            iScore = 0;
            pbScore.setProgress(iScore);
        }
    }

cdtScore = new QuestionTimer(60000, 1000);
cdtScore.start();
```

Comment: where you are testing this?

Comment: @Sree, on real mobile. HTC One M9+

Comment: can you able to check this on any other device,?

Comment: @Sree, let me check it out.

Comment: if not working set like this - progressBar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.RED, Mode.SRC_IN);

Comment: @Sree, yeah, but I need that particular color. I have tested other colors on my mobile and it is working fine. I have issue only with this color.

Comment: Lets define this color in color.xml file and call like R.color.yourcolor

Comment: @Sree, tried by calling color from color.xml but having same issue.

Comment: are you still using Color.parseColor  when calling color?

Comment: @Sree, yes. I also tried on another mobile but have same issue.

Comment: Why you dot try with out Color.parseColor

Comment: @Sree, I already tried. But Still have same issue.

Comment: one more question, in which version you are testing this ? i mean android version

Comment: ok can you able to post your whole progressbar code please

Comment: @Sree, check updated post.

Comment: look this http://www.scriptscoop.com/t/24d5121333ff/android-setting-progress-bar-color-to-default-prior-to-api-21.html i think your progress get confused and showing that color

Comment: @Sree, no, if i use any another color there then it is working fine.

Comment: really unfortunate.. but why that is not working

Comment: @Sree, I am also being confused.

Comment: getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(0xFFFF0000,android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY) what about this one?

Comment: @Sree, let me try it.

Comment: @Sree, If i use `Mode.SRC_IN` then it is showing perfect color but it is of no use. Having issue only with `Mode.MULTIPLY`. and no effect with getIndeterminateDrawable.

Comment: hmm, really this is going crazy

Comment: @Sree, yes. Is there any another option to get progress effect without using Mode.MULTIPLY ???

Comment: i dot know, but look this http://android-er.blogspot.in/2015/02/various-effect-of-porterduffmode-when.html